# Back windows up with ability to keep most recent files

Tags: windows-10, disk-image, windows-backup, incremental-backup

My issue is, Windows 10 would not boot. When I pushed it to safe mode, I saw a message saying

> We couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes. Don't turn off your computer

The loop didn't end no matter what advice I followed (System Restore or 
Automatic Repair), but my question **isn't** about solving this issue.

My question is how can I restore the PC (all aps etc) to last known good yet keep all the files that are most up to date.

I hope this gives a better insight if my question isn't clear:

Windows has the option to repair Windows but keep all your files. Alternatively, nuke and restart. There is also back up media which I think, depending on settings etc, will allow images to be taken which will store everything (it's an image).

From what I've read up is, I *think*, the problem with the image is, any changes which were made between the last time the image was taken and the point at which I try to restore from an image means files will be lost.

Again, my question is, how can I restore the PC (all aps etc) to last known good yet keep all the files that are most up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is Windows that is broken, not the disk, so you just need to
repair Windows and keep your files. No need to reinstall Windows.

Boot from a Windows 10 boot media and choose *Repair*, then *Troubleshoot* and finally
*Advanced options*. The most useful options here for you are:

- **System Restore**: Restore your computer to an earlier restore point. This is the same as using System Restore within Windows and is the closest to the option of
  restoring the computer to the last known good configuration.
- **Automatic Repair**: Try to automatically repair issues that can prevent Windows from booting properly. Worth a try if your computer can’t boot.
- **Command Prompt**: Open a Recovery Environment Command Prompt for manually
  fixing the computer, if you are an advanced user.

In the command prompt, you may return yourself the registry to its backup from
`C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack`, the same as you could in Windows 7
as a boot option, but this backup may be from too far ago.
See for example
[How to restore Registry from its secret backup on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/restore-registry-backup-windows-10/).

If you cannot get to these options, or if they don't help, your next
step is *Reset This PC* with the *Keep My Files* option:

[image]

If you can still boot into Safe mode, or if you can't then into the
Command Prompt, save first all your data to external media,
before doing any of these manipulations.
Even *Reset This PC* with the *Keep My Files* option can fail disastrously.

Comment: Hi. I guess my question was not clear. Those did not help. The boot process remained in a loop. I tried restore, automatic repair. I didn't do anything with the command prompt. However, may be I've miss understood. If I boot from Windows 10 Boot Media, is that different to the normal repair options I get

Comment: I added it in, but try everything, remembering first to *backup your data*!

Comment: `My question is how can I restore the PC (all aps etc) to last known good yet keep all the files that are most up to date. ` How does your solution allow me to keep all aps?

Comment: My answer goes in ascending order of severity and lose. To keep your apps, you may use a restore point, or the command line for restoring  the registry backup. If this does not help, let us know how they fail. In any case, after such a catastrophic failure, you would be lucky to save as much as possible. Myself, I take a disk image backup of the system disk every week, just in case, as Windows is fragile and the most dangerous is Windows Update.

Comment: Actually, your comment about taking an image weekly is very helpful! It is what I alluded to in my answer, but there will be a period of lost of work if you have to restore from the image

Comment: Remembering what apps you installed last week is possible ;)